# How to filter an array of different types using TypeScript and specifying the explicit type?

Tags: typescript

I have a class with two fields. These fields are arrays of different types, but they have the common field `id`. So, I want to implement the method that filters the array and remove the item by provided id.

```typescript
enum ItemType {
  VEGETABLES = 'vegetables',
  FRUITS = 'fruits'
}

class BaseVegetable {
  id: string = '';
  color: string = '';
}
class BaseFruit {
  id: string = '';
  description?: any;
}

class Basket {
  vegetables: BaseVegetable[] = [];
  fruits: BaseFruit[] = [];

  removeItem(id: string, type: ItemType) {
    this[type] = this[type].filter(item => id !== item.id);
  }
}
```

This example in TS Playground
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgLsCAVAngB2FA3gKClANQFEBxIpAQQCEAZIgZSgF4oByAN2AHNg4BDAEYAbYAGdWAGjxQAYgCUAqjCSMWrAGYAnMAEs44nAF8cOAMZC+o0VCqXgBbr0Ejs0nQBMAXFFFxNOkC5mNlYAbmlTAHshSM1vX39A4NYwozMLKxs7GW09V3wPeL8AoLVU-HcxU380OB1IkAB+bz4QFHDjdMtrW1EAa158qE4efmExb177RzGRAG0AXWDF8PwtXX1J7Ny4ReWF8OlNREjOeEQACkKfYsCJKDh0YG9z5CeASiH8KJBfKD5gnAABY6URzR4YA4mfD4YGg8FPJYsOFgiHABYAOnUOiECE0VwQ0CYAD4oB4oABCJgsPSIDEed6rKDGQxAA)

Now I'm getting the typescript error

> This expression is not callable.
> Each member of the union type '{ (predicate: (value: BaseVegetable, index: number, array: BaseVegetable[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (predicate: (value: BaseVegetable, index: number, array: BaseVegetable[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): BaseVegetable[]; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.(2349)

And `item` within the filter function has `any` type.
Though if I write something like `const a = this[type]` I get the correct type `BaseVegetable[] | BaseFruit[]`.

Could you help me please to understand the reason of the error?
Is it possible to implement the remove function in this way and describe it correctly with TS?

Comment: TS can't deal with *correlated unions* as described in [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581);  `this[type] = this[type].filter(item => id !== item.id)` is only okay if you check it multiple times, once for each possible narrowing of `type`. But TS can't do that. The recommended fix is described in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves refactoring to generic indexed accesses and mapped types, as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/mZZMDm). Does that address the q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I suppose yes, it's connected with correlated unions. The solution looks a bit weird but it really works. Thank you for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because TypeScript cannot follow *correlations* between multiple [union-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) expressions, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

When TypeScript analyzes the following code:

```
this[type] = this[type].filter(item => id !== item.id)
```

it sees that `this[type]` is `BaseVegetable[] | BaseFruit[]`, a union of array types, and there are problems calling `filter` on unions (see [microsoft/TypeScript#44373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373)).  Even if you could resolve that it would only see that the right hand side is `BaseVegetable[] | BaseFruit[]`, and this might not be appropriate to write to a property of `this` at a key of type `ItemType`, as enforced in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769).  The compiler is correct to stop people from doing that *in general*, as shown here:

```
demo(typeRead: ItemType, typeWrite: ItemType) {    
  this[typeWrite] = this[typeRead]; // this fails because it's not safe
}
```

Because what if you are writing to a different property from the one you read? The reason you know your code is safe is that you are using an *identical* variable `type` on each side. But TypeScript doesn't check *identity* here, it's checking *type*.

Essentially TypeScript can only check a single block of code one time.  The compiler doesn't speculatively narrow `type` to `ItemType.VEGETABLES` and then speculatively narrow `type` to `ItemType.FRUITS` and check each case.  If it did, then the compiler could see that it works in both cases.  But it doesn't, because it would result in catastrophically bad compiler performance for all but the simplest of programs if the compiler automatically checked every code block as many times as number of all possible union narrowings.  Maybe it would work if developers could opt into it as needed, but that approach was suggested and declined in [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051).

---

To resolve the error, you can follow the recommendations described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to refactor your operations away from unions and toward [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), because generics let you write a single block of code that represents a range of cases at once.  And the compiler is much better at analyzing generics, especially generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

Here's how it looks for your example:

```
class Basket {
  vegetables: BaseVegetable[] = [];
  fruits: BaseFruit[] = [];
  removeItem<K extends ItemType>(id: string, type: K) {
    const thiz: { [P in K]: Basket[P][number][] } = this; // okay
    thiz[type] = thiz[type].filter(item => id !== item.id); // okay
  }
}
```

We made `removeItem` generic in `K`, the type of `type`.  When `type` appears multiple times in the function, the compiler is more willing to treat the generic type `K` as being "the same" on the left and right side of the assignment. That would allow `this[type] = this[type];` to work, but not the filter.

In order for the compiler to understand the filtering, we need `this[type]` to itself be a generic of the form `F<K>[]` for some `F`.  We can do this by rewriting `this` as a mapped type: `{ [P in K]: Basket[P][number][] }` which is saying: each property of `this` an `ItemType` key is an array of the array elements of the corresponding property of `Basket`.  It's kind of a tautology.  So when `K` is `ItemType` you get `{vegetables: Basket["vegetables"][number][], fruits: Basket["fruits"][number][]}` and therefore `{vegetables: BaseVegetable[], fruits: BaseFruit[]}`. The compiler is happy with the assignment of `this` to that type, so it allows

```
const thiz: { [P in K]: Basket[P][number][] } = this; // okay
```

One might think this isn't an improvement, but refactoring that type allows the compiler to see `thiz[type]` explicitly as a single array type that's generic in `K`:

```
const thizType: Basket[K][number][] = thiz[Type];
```

And therefore you can `filter()` it and get `Basket[K][number][]` on both sides of the assignment, which the compiler accepts:

```
    thiz[type] = thiz[type].filter(item => id !== item.id); // okay
```

So that's the way you can fix it while getting some type safety from the compiler.

---

Of course that refactoring might not be worth it to you.  If you just want to suppress the error and move on, you could use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that you're doing the right thing (even if how you convince it is a lie):

```
removeItem(id: string, type: ItemType) {
  this[type] = (this[type] as
    { id: string }[]).filter(item => id !== item.id
    ) as (BaseVegetable & BaseFruit)[];
}
```

That works; saying that `this[type]` is a `{id: string}[]` is more or less true, but saying that the filter result is a `(BaseVegetable & BaseFruit)[]` is a lie.  Either way the compiler accepts it. This won't catch errors (if you changed `this[type] =`  to `this.vegetables =` the compiler won't notice), so you'd need to be more careful this way.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgLsCAVAngB2FA3gKClANQFEBxIpAQQCEAZIgZSgF4oByAN2AHNg4BDAEYAbYAGdWAGjxQAYgCUAqjCSMWrAGYAnMAEs44nAF8cOAMZC+o0VCqXgBbr0Ejs0nQBMAXFFFxNOkC5mNlYAbmlTAHshSM1vX39A4NYwozMLKxs7GW09V3wPeL8AoLVU-HcxU380OB1IkAB+bz4QFHDjdMtrW1EAa158qE4efmExb177RzGRAG0AXWDF8PwtXX1J7Ny4ReWF1ahNREjOeEQAHgBpKGAADwQQd2tz5HRgAD4ACkKfYsCJFA4O9vFcAJSuaT4KIgXxAgAWOgAXt4sFA5gAFKABKBXBZbfq8TELObgCACYCaElLQzBOCI0SHaENOH05GoDB0xFIubAjAHKFQAD0QqgMNZ3I5wFR6KxOLxBIGuwxJLJFKpKyghjmeMF4rgCPZ7wATIqiXjSZB1dSuUaMEzDTy+cAliw2U73gsAHTqHRCBCaH4IaBMD7Y9xQACETBYekQXo8YMOnXwxwgp2Ar2NPy8f0SXEBzu8rylENw+HwbNEvM9wS+VZr-KglkF+DRvwSJS1izBPr9AaDiGYYY8UZj2ODCfcragEMsUC+Uwco2cmAAZFlRMAchswStpMZOuowCBTHUGlBff7KTAQBiLKZgBckN87t4kItAaYBN4vux34COjeGqlKAnwmhxFAH4LBCoZQAIkTRMArRltIdxeqIaBCDoj5fAADIC6EiIE9KAl65HoVeA7fmCSZGEAA)